# Message notification for user

Tags: functions, ajax, user-meta

I want to create alert system for users. If user get message I want to show info andout it near user image in header.
So I create table for message

id_message | id_user | sender_name | sender_email | subject | sender_text | datatime

also I want to add meta key and meta value for each user - when user check messages.

So I add this code to header.php. I want to check if user has last_seen meta value - if not I want to create it

```
if ( metadata_exists( 'user', $user_id, $meta_key ) ) 
{
    $user_last_seen = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, true );
    $last_message_time = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM ej_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'last_seen' AND user_id = ".$user_id );
    if ( $last_message_time > $user_last_seen ){
        <a href="/messages"><p>New message</p></a>
    }
}
else 
{
    $meta_value = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    add_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_seen', $meta_value, true );
}
```

Update meta key last_seen when user click on messages

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="current-user-id" value="<?php get_current_user_id();?>">
```

Send user id to function update_last_seen_value

```
jQuery(".current-user-id").on('click', function () {
  var id = $(".current-user-id").attr("id");
  jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: ajaxurl,
      data: {"action": "update_last_seen_value", "id": id},
      success: function (data) {
         
      }
  });
});
```

Code in function.php for updating last_seen value

```
function update_last_seen_value() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table = 'ej_users';
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $meta_value = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    update_user_meta( $id , 'last_seen', $meta_value );
}
```

But it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `wp_ajax` action to callback your function.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_last_seen_value', 'update_last_seen_value' );
function update_last_seen_value() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table = 'ej_users';
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $meta_value = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    update_user_meta( $id , 'last_seen', $meta_value );
        $data = array(
            "status"     => 'success'
        );
    echo json_encode($data);
    die();
}
```

I have used your code and made correction to render scenario to my machine.

header.php file should be as per my understanding. You can make change as per your requirement.

```
<?php 
if(is_user_logged_in())
{
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $meta_key = 'last_seen';
    if ( metadata_exists( 'user', $user_id, $meta_key ) ) 
    {
        $user_last_seen = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, true );
        if ( !empty($user_last_seen ))
        {  ?>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="message-link"><p>New message</p></a>
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="current-user-id" value="<?php echo get_current_user_id();?>">
            <?php
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $meta_value = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_seen', $meta_value, true );
    }
}
```

jQuery snippet

```
   jQuery(".message-link").on('click', function () {
        var id = jQuery(".current-user-id").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {"action": "update_last_seen_value", "id": id},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Please check above code and let me know if you have any questions related this. I have tested and it is working fine for me.

Comment: Also I have table with messages and message table has datatime fiel. And I want to show message alert only if I have new message. So I try  $last_message_time = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT datetime FROM ej_user_messages WHERE id_user = ".$user_id."ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1" );
        if ( $last_message_time > $user_last_seen )
        {  ?>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="message-link"><p>New message</p></a>
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="current-user-id" value="<?php echo get_current_user_id();?>">
            <?php
        }

Comment: when I try to see results of query I get Array ( ) - I get empty resuts. So I can't use if else

Comment: It seems problem with Query $last_message_time = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT 'datetime' FROM ej_user_messages WHERE id_user = ".$user_id."ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1" );

Comment: Yes, you need to check last seen and last message time using strtotime function. the mail problem was you did not use wp_ajax.